# Apache long delay with incoming requests

Tags: apache, apache2

Pardon any wrong wording, as I'm fairly new to Apache.

I'm testing a web store website using some automation scripts where the payment portion goes off to another server, then back to the original server. The delay happens when the automation script is returning from the payment gateway server and back to the original web store site. The delay is pretty consistently between 5 and 10 MINUTES.

I am using Ruby with the Mechanize gem, but that doesn't seem to be the problem.

The payment portion is a very simple PHP app.

Here's a bit from the log showing the massive delay. Domains and such removed for the eyes of the public:

```
[19/Jul/2011:01:49:39 +0000] "GET HTTP/1.1" 401 672 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_2; de-at) AppleWebKit/531.21.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Safari/531.21.10"
[19/Jul/2011:01:49:39 +0000] "GET HTTP/1.1" 200 12934 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_2; de-at) AppleWebKit/531.21.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Safari/531.21.10"
[19/Jul/2011:01:49:39 +0000] "POST HTTP/1.1" 302 488 "..." "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_2; de-at) AppleWebKit/531.21.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Safari/531.21.10"
[19/Jul/2011:01:49:39 +0000] "GET HTTP/1.1" 200 5146 "..." "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_2; de-at) AppleWebKit/531.21.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Safari/531.21.10"
[19/Jul/2011:01:49:39 +0000] "POST HTTP/1.1" 302 465 "..." "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_2; de-at) AppleWebKit/531.21.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Safari/531.21.10"
[19/Jul/2011:01:49:39 +0000] "GET HTTP/1.1" 302 330 "..." "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_2; de-at) AppleWebKit/531.21.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Safari/531.21.10"
[19/Jul/2011:01:49:39 +0000] "GET HTTP/1.1" 200 5262 "..." "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_2; de-at) AppleWebKit/531.21.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Safari/531.21.10"
[19/Jul/2011:01:49:44 +0000] "POST HTTP/1.1" 200 6821 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10_6_2; de-at) AppleWebKit/531.21.8 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0.4 Safari/531.21.10"
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Jul/2011:01:53:46 +0000] "OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0" 200 152 "-" "Apache/2.2.14 (Ubuntu) (internal dummy connection)"
```

I am just using IP addresses, so DNS does not play a role.

Let me know if you need any more information. Thanks!

Comment: Do you know where the delay is? sending the request or waiting for the response? - Check your DNS and be sure everything resolves correctly as well.

Comment: How can I determine where the delay is? Thanks.

Comment: Well,you are going to have to do some testing with the gateway's api. do they have any debugging features? can you get support from their tech? - also it's hard to say, you've removed urls from the log - but I see 302/401 errors in there - and nothing indicating a lag of any kind.

Comment: I want to point out the delay in the last two lines. The 4 minute delay is there.